# Accessing the first <section> within unknown number of divs

Tags: html, css

Given the following markup:

```
<div className="row">
    <noscript></noscript>
</div>
<div className="row">
    <noscript></noscript>
</div>
<div className="row">
    <section></section>
</div>
<div className="row">
    <section></section>
</div>
<div className="row">
    <section></section>
</div>
...
```

**There may be any number of divs at the top that contain `noscript`.**

How can I access only the first `section` in the `row`s?

Comment: I doubt it's possible with pure CSS. You'll have to use JS.

Answer (score 2):

It won't be possible to achieve this using **CSS** only, you need to use **Javascript**.

**Explanation:**

Because `:nth-of-type(1)`, `nth-child()`, `:first-of-type` and `:first-child` will always give you all the sections as they are the first child and the first of type `section` in their parents div.

All these selectors will only work, if you are putting all the sections inside one parent div with `class="row"`.

**JavaScript solution:**

You can use `document.querySelector(".row section")` to get the first section in a div with `class="row"`.

But with **CSS** only this won't be possible:

```js
document.querySelector(".row section").innerHTML = "I am the first section !";
```

```css
.row {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <noscript></noscript>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <noscript></noscript>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <section></section>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <section></section>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <section></section>
</div>
```

**Note:**

Also in **HTML** it's `class="row"` and not `className="row"`, in fact `className` is used in **Javascript**.

Comment: I should have mentioned I'm using React

Comment: @alanbuchanan I think it will be the same Javascript code with react.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to @chsdk, you could use the jQuery method of .first()

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <noscript></noscript>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <noscript></noscript>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <section>1</section>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <section>2</section>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <section>3</section>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.row {
  display:block;
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
}

section {
  display:block;
  height:20px;
  width:20px;
}
```

jQuery

```
$('.row section').first().css('background','#111');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ojuun4uh/

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript, the [**getElementsByTagName**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName) method can help you. Try this:

```
var section = document.getElementsByTagName('section').item(0);
```